# приложения андроид не видят медиа файлы

Tags: android, termux

Если я перемещу какую-нибудь картинку в Termux командой cp pic.png /sdcard/Pictures/, то например в телеграмме или галерее его не появится, только через пару дней (но это долго). Однако в любом explore этот файл существует и его можно открыть.

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

чтобы решить проблему надо использовать команду termux-media-scan [file]